# How to perform digit by digit multiplication in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function which multiplies numbers digit by digit, like we did in school. For example, in 445 * 456, we first multiply 5 by 6, then, 4 and again 4. Then, we multiply 4 by 5 and so on. I want to do this for getting answers in strings for very very long multiplications.

Here, numArray is digits stored in array, e.g 563 is [5, 6, 3];
Similarily, another number can be e.g. 621 which is converted into [6, 2, 1]

```
   for(var i = 1; i <= anotherNumArray.length; i++) {
        var multiplier = anotherNumArray[anotherNumArray.length-i]
        for(var j = 1; j <= numArray.length; j++) {
            var multiplicand = numArray[numArray.length-j]
            answer.unshift(multiplicand*multiplier);
   }
```

I am trying to loop multiplication of numbers. But I am getting weird results.

Comment: Good start: you've explained what you want to do, and you've shown the code you've written... But: you haven't yet explained what you expected this to do, what it actually does, and what/where you've already investigated to figure out why there's a mismatch.

Comment: What is `anotherNumArray`, `newAnoNumArr` and `numArray` here?

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to have custom multiplication function for strings?

Comment: I have updated question again, please check that and help me.

Comment: Like @Mike said, some explanation of what you have done and what you expect would have helped. Also a more complete piece of code since we are missing the arrays and their meaning. In any case I've answered the best I could, I hope it does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want an algorithm that multiplies two n-digit numbers using the [Long multiplication method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) that most of us were taught in school.

Here is my approach (excessively commented so you understand what it does):

```js
var n1 = [5, 6, 3]; // multiplicand
var n2 = [6, 2, 1]; // multiplier

var expectedResult = parseInt(n1.join('')) * parseInt(n2.join(''));
console.log('expectedResult = ' + expectedResult);

var partialProducts = [];
var product = '';

// Iterate over the multiplier from right to left
for (var i = n2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var d2 = n2[i];
  var carry = 0;
  
  // Iterate over the multiplicand from right to left
  for (var j = n1.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var d1 = n1[j];
    
    // Perform the multiplication
    var mult = (d2 * d1) + carry;
    
    // Recalculate the carry for the next iteration
    carry = Math.floor(mult / 10);
    
    // add the last number of the multiplication
    product = (mult % 10) + product;
  }
  
  // Add the remaining carry in case theres some left
  product = (carry % 10) + product;
  
  // Add a new product to the partialProducts array
  // shifted the needed places to the left
  var shift = (10 ** (n2.length - i - 1));
  partialProducts.push(product * shift);
  
  // A new product was pushed, clear it for the next iteration
  product = '';
}

// Finally, just sumate all the partial products
var result = partialProducts.reduce((a, c) => a + c);
console.log('result = ' + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is more complicated than presented

assuming actual "long multiplication" simulation, i.e only digits multiplication and summation allowed, see below comments and working code.

first of all, the code is ignoring the fact that multiplications of two digits will overflow and will yield a non-zero carry value that should be summed with the next multiplication

secondly, as we've been tought in school, for each digit, we recieve a new multiplication result with all other digits of the second number. we will need to sum over those multiplication results in the end

code below works for non-negative decimal numbers. it could be simplified, but have tried to keep the spirit of the initial algorithm

```
// parameters
const lhs = "445";
const rhs = "456";

// utilities
const createZeros = length => new Array(length).fill(0);
const padArrayEnd = (length, padding, array) => [...array, ...createZeros(length - array.length)];
const last = array => array[array.length - 1];

// given a carray and an array of digits, add the carry to the last digit.
// if the result overflows, add the remainder as a new digit instead
// example;
//   array = [3, 4, 5]; addCarry(2, array); array == [3, 4, 7]
//   array = [3, 4, 9]; addCarry(2, array); array == [3, 4, 0, 1]
function addCarry(carry, digits) {
    if (carry == 0) {
        return;
    }

    let value = last(digits) + carry;
    if (value > 10) {
        digits[digits.length - 1] = 0;
        digits.unshift(value % 10);
    } else {
        digits[digits.length - 1] = value;
    }
}

console.log({ message: "start", lhs, rhs });

// state
const answer = [];
const entries = [];
let carry = 0;

// perform digit by digit multiplication.
// remember that the result array for each digit should have N leading zeros, where N is the position of that digit.
// this is the reason we keep an array of entries. each entry, is the result array corresponding to that digit
for(let lcur = 0; lcur < lhs.length; lcur++) {
    const leftDigit = lhs[lhs.length - 1 - lcur];

    // the multiplications entry
    const multiplications = createZeros(lcur);

    for(let rcur = 0; rcur < rhs.length; rcur++) {
        const rightDigit = rhs[rhs.length - 1 - rcur];

        // perform multiplication, but notice that in case of overflow we keep
        // only the ones, and remember carry for next iteration
        const times = (leftDigit * rightDigit) + carry;
        const ones = times % 10;
        carry = Math.floor(times / 10);

        multiplications.unshift(ones);
        console.log({ message: "step", expr: `${leftDigit} * ${rightDigit}`, times, ones, carry });
    }

    if (carry != 0){
        multiplications.unshift(carry);
        carry = 0;
    }

    // update entries
    entries.push(multiplications); 
    console.log({ message: "entry", multiplications });
}

// add the final carry
addCarry(carry, last(entries));

console.log({ message: "entries", entries });

// sum all entries with carries
const maxLength = entries
    .map(entry => entry.length)
    .reduce((acc, entry) => Math.max(acc, entry), 0);

// for convinience, reverse all entries - this can by bypassed with messing around with indices
entries.forEach(entry => entry.reverse());

carry = 0;
for (let idx = 0; idx < maxLength; ++idx) {
    const sum = entries
        .map(entry => entry[idx] || 0)
        .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, carry);

    const ones = sum % 10;
    carry = Math.floor(sum / 10);

    answer.unshift(ones);
    console.log({ message: "summation", sum, ones, carry, answer });
}

// add final summation carry
// remember that we reversed stuff before, reverse back
// answer.reverse()
addCarry(carry, answer);

// finalize a result 
const result = answer.join("");
const expected = (parseInt(lhs) * parseInt(rhs)).toString(); // string for some reason
console.log({ message: "finish", expr: `${lhs} * ${rhs} = ${answer.join("")}`, answer, expected });
```